# Inserting checkbox value into Mongodb using Springboot

Tags: html, mongodb, spring-boot, checkbox

I am new to springboot, How to insert a checkbox value  (frontend) into mongodb using springboot(backend).

Comment: For low-level work use official Mongo DB driver and learn how to do [write operations](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/driver/tutorials/perform-write-operations/). If you're looking for something more advanced then check [Hibernate OGM](https://hibernate.org/ogm/).

Comment: actually I am using  springboot as backend